# How to reduce the running time for finding the last non-zero digit of factorial of a number?

Tags: java, c, time-complexity, factorial

I got a question in which I have to find the last non-zero digit of factorial of a number.I used same code for java and C but it takes different time in both.

```
int lastDigitDiffZero(long n) {

     int dig[] = {1, 1, 2, 6, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 8};
     int i=(int) n;

     if (n < 10)
       return dig[i]; 

     if (((n/10)%10)%2 == 0)
       return (6*lastDigitDiffZero(n/5)*dig[(int)n%10]) % 10;
     else
       return (4*lastDigitDiffZero(n/5)*dig[(int)n%10]) % 10;
}
```

I want to know why does it takes different time and what should I do to reduce the running time?

Comment: java code will take more execution time. because bytecode is compiled by jvm into machine level instructions. C code will be faster than java. Please read about java virtual machine and why java is platform independent, you will have your answer.

Comment: java has a JVM below. it increases the time of compilation/interpretation/execution

Comment: The JVM although increases the time can do automatic optimisation, usually after each 10K cpu cycles, thus give it a "warming time" before you check execution time
also you can disable the garbage collector if your code is simple and don't create/delete a lot of objects, this will increase performance

Comment: `@akshayapandey` has given the answer to your first question. For the second one you might want to make a post on [CodeReview](codereview.stackexchange.com); note that working code is mandatory there

Comment: Your function is named misleadingly (you even accepted an answer to a different question). Use `leastSignificantDigitInFactorial()`, better yet, document it using [doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/docblocks.html) (or better).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just:

```
private static int lastDigitDiffZero(long n)
{
   int temp = (int) n;
   int mod = temp%10;

  return (mod == 0 ? lastDigitDiffZero(temp/10) : mod);
}
```

Comment: 2! is 6, but this gives 2: how is this an alternative `to find the last non-zero digit of factorial of a number`?

Answer (score 1):

Please find the optimized version :

```
private static final int DIG[] = { 1, 1, 2, 6, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 8 };

static int lastDigitDiffZero(long n) {
        if (n < 10)
            return DIG[(int) n];
        int t1 = (int) (n % 10);
        int t2 = lastDigitDiffZero(n / 5) * DIG[t1];
        if (((n / 10) % 10) % 2 == 0) {
            return (6 * t2) % 10;
        } else
            return (4 * t2) % 10;
}
```